# Installing NVIDIA driver 375.26 fails after kernel upgrade to 4.9.0-5-amd64

Tags: linux-kernel, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

Setup is a XPS 15 9560 with Nvidia gtx 1050 mobile gpu. I know it's an optimus system but I do not want to install bumblebee for various reasons. Anyways, I had successfully installed the driver with *NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.26.run* file while running kernel version *4.9.0-4-amd64*. After the kernel upgrade, X was no longer using the `nvidia` driver so I uninstalled it, installed the new `linux-headers`, rebooted into runlevel 3, and when attempting to reinstall it failed.

Here is [/var/log/nvidia-installer.log](https://pastebin.com/7v3uiZyA).

I have blacklisted `nouveau` in */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf*

---

```
lsmod | grep -e nouveau -e rivafb -e nvidiafb
```

output is empty

---

```
$ uname -a  
Linux debian 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
$ cc -v :  
gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18)
```

---

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.9.0-5-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04)
```

---

Looks like the same `gcc` version used to compile the currently running kernel and the Nvidia kernel module are exactly the same, so then is there something else I'm missing?

UPDATE: I had installed `tlp` shortly after the initial installation of the nvidia driver which is when this issue actually began. I uninstalled `tlp` then the driver installed flawlessly just like before.

Comment: relevant kernel error from the log (line 328 at your paste)  `The NVIDIA GPU 0000:01:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1c8d) installed in this system is not supported by the 375.26 NVIDIA Linux driver release.`

Comment: Yes, I understand the driver it’s not supported on my system. This has not prevented me from installing the driver and X using my nvidia card, as I said, I have done this before. Could you help explain why I was able to install and load the driver while on kernel version 4.9.0-4?

Comment: i can't explain, but thought it was the most relevant snippet in the linked log, and posted as a comment to signal boost to anyone else looking.  re: `tlp`: perhaps power mgmt had disabled the device?  i'm not sure that explains the kernel error from the log though.  see [archwiki on tlp and bumblebee](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP#Bumblebee_with_NVIDIA_driver).

Comment: Thank you, quixotic, I truly appreciate your help. I guess there's a known problem with tlp power mgmt interfering with nvidia cards. I reinstalled tlp and followed the directions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:Bumblebee#Bumblebee_and_TLP_interferening) and was able to install the driver with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

So, even though I am not using Bumblebee, the [solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP#Bumblebee_with_NVIDIA_driver) is to either uninstall tlp all together or just disable tlp power management capabilities for GPU.